# no such column: Blog_post.category_id

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I’m trying to create a category for each post.
I made another class with the same models.py and in the same class Post I made a category = models.ForeignKey

But it keeps showing me this error when I run the server:

> (no such column: Blog_post.category_id)

Ps: I did run the makemigrations and the migrate command.
The tutorial I followed just added the model as it is in models.py but should I also make a function for the views.py or its just a model problem ?

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Post(models.Model): 
 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="Some random thing")
    werkstoffnummer = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def __str__(self):
    return self.werkstoffnummer
    
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

views.py

```
from random import choices
from unicodedata import category
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, get_list_or_404, HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import (ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView)
from .models import Post, Category
from django.db.models import Q
import pandas as pd
import json
import os


def home(request):
    context = {"posts": Post.objects.all()}
    return render(request, "Blog/home.html", context)

def werkstoffdaten(request):
    context = {"posts": Post.objects.all()}
    return render(request, "Blog/werkstoffdaten.html", context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "Blog/werkstoffdaten.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = "posts"
    ordering = \["-date_posted"\]
    paginate_by = 100

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "Blog/home.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = "posts"
    ordering = \["-date_posted"\]
    paginate_by = 100


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "Blog/user_posts.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = "posts"
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get("username"))    
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by("-date_posted")
        


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = \[
        "werkstoffnummer", "werkstoffbezeichnung",

    \]


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)




class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = \[
        "werkstoffnummer", "werkstoffbezeichnung",

    \]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False



class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = "/"

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False




def Periodic_Table(request):
    return render(request, "Blog/Periodic_Table.html")

def user_manual(request):
    return render(request, "Blog/user_manual.html")

def about(request):
    return render(request, "Blog/about.html", {"title": "About"})

def search_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST.get("searched")
        posts = Post.objects.filter(
            Q(werkstoffnummer=searched) | Q(werkstoffbezeichnung=searched) | Q(gruppe=searched)
        )

        return render(
            request, "Blog/search_post.html", {"searched": searched, "posts": posts}
        )
    else:
        return render(request, "Blog/search_post.html", {})




def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response\['Content-Disposition'\] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

OperationalError at / [image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiZeD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Delete `default="Some random thing"` in your category field, `default` value for foreign key of your `Category` model, must be a private key (`pk` (aka `id` (type == `integer`))), but `not the string`.

If you just delete this default value, it will work, or you can put `default=1` as first object of your `Category` models would be default for your new `Post` objects

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

or

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

Comment: I tried both, it didn't work. Keeps showing me |no such column: Blog_post.category_id|

Comment: how to change this exactly>??
must be a private key (pk (aka id (type == integer))), but not the string.

Comment: delete your database `db.sqlite3`, then create it again, by doing this two steps `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` it will create new database for you, i believe it might be corrupted, code is legit. ||||  your `default="Some random thing"` value `default="Some random thing"`  is a string here, it is only explanation of what i wrote

Comment: I tried that, nothing happened. It's the same outcome

Comment: attach code from `views.py` how you execute any logic with database, and please attach more of your error code

Comment: I just edit the post

Comment: try to temporary delete your base.html, error occur during its render. Do you have `Blog_post` model?

Comment: no Blog_post model, i did delete base.html having other error. it say TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Blog/base.html

Comment: I do have the Post(models.Model)